# Why .NET Core Web Application initially boots as Console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Below is the `Program.cs` file which has `Main()`, the main method is the entry point in .NET Core. Why .NET Core Web Application has main method and why does it initially boots as Console Application?

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Comment: Because it **is** a console app. All non-WinForms/WPF netcore projects are (save Blazor client side)

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 its a web application still, it initially starts as console, my question was why does it boots as a console even though it is a web application

Comment: @RafaelBiz Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @VishalD . . . Perhaps you are confused with the term *web application* here. What do you consider to be a web application? In technical regard, an ASP.NET web application is a backend/server application, which is responsible for rendering frontend browser (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) or API (XML, JSON) content. You can configure and compile an ASP.NET web application to run in IIS or other webservers, but with .NET Core it is typically a console application that embeds the Kestrel engine (or another suitable webhost), so that it can run independently from a webserver.

Comment: @BartHofland I mean to say .net core MVC or web API , thanks for the information

Comment: Even running inside of IIS, it still runs as a console application. The web config and the settings for the hosting module literally invoke the same Exe.. (or via dotnet dllname) . Perhaps you are confused by the console window appearing? That's literally how all the applications run, because they are just all plain old window-less applications which rely on the console. Hidden behind IIS or not

Answer (score 5):

The ASP.NET Core web application is actually a console project, which starts executing from the entry point `public static void Main()` in the Program class where we can create a host for the web application. The host is responsible for app startup and lifetime management. At a minimum, the host configures a server and a request processing pipeline. The host can also set up logging, dependency injection, and configuration. More detail information, you could refer the following articles:

[.NET Generic Host in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[ASP.NET Core Web Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[What Is Startup Class And Program.cs In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/what-is-startup-class-and-program-cs-in-asp-net-core/)